# # of jobs lost after selecting Any Job Type

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

When you first go to **search jobs** you are given the number of total jobs listed at the top.  As you hover over the keywords filter you are given a drop down to select any of the following: Any, Permanent, and Contract.  As I click these I can see the number of jobs for Permanent and Contract but if I click Any this number is lost.

Any way we can keep that number listed?

Answer (score 1):

When you do a search where all of the criteria have their default values (i.e. search terms are empty, location is empty, no location options are checked, employment relationship type = All, and no sort option is specified) then the results are sorted according to our "matches" algo. In this state, we do not bother showing the job count because we limit the result set to a single page.

If you were to click "most recent" to apply a recency sort, the normal job count display kicks in.